# Include an ampersand in an XML attribute

Tags: xml, dom, powershell, html-entities, xml-attribute

## The problem

We want to assign an attribute whose contents already contain entities like `&quot;` or `&amp;`.

In this example, we want the title attribute to be `Stack "Stacky" Overflow`:

```js
$elem = $xml.CreateElement("Site");
$elem.SetAttribute("Title", "Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow");
```

But that turns into the following piece of XML output:

```xml
<Site Title="Stack &amp;quot;Stacky&amp;quot; Overflow" />
```

That behaviour is even stated in the documentation about the [XmlElement.SetAttribute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw.aspx):

> In order to assign an attribute value that contains entity references,
>   the user must create an [XmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx) node plus any [XmlText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltext.aspx) and
>   [XmlEntityReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlentityreference.aspx) nodes, build the appropriate subtree and use
>   [SetAttributeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattributenode.aspx) to assign it as the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The solution

```js
$elem = $xml.CreateElement("Site");

$elemAttr = $xml.CreateAttribute("Title");
$elemAttr.InnerXml = "Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow";

$elem.SetAttributeNode($elemAttr);
```

XML output:

```
<Site Title="Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow" />
```

Comment: instead of InnerXml, can use attr value:
  $elemAttr.value = "Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow";

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this helps

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$elem = $xml.CreateElement("Site");
$elem.SetAttribute("Title",[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode("Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow"));
$elem.OuterXml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> $xml.Site.Title = [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape('Stack "Stacky" Overflow')
PS> $xml.Site.Title

Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow
```

Comment: This is also a solution, of course. But in my case, I have got tons of sequences of `&quot` in my string. I think my solution is the more simple one in that situation. There's also the possibility of calling an entity decode function (I don't know the exact name in PS).

Comment: Have you tries setting it the simple way? $xml.Site.Title = 'Stack &quot;Stacky&quot; Overflow'

Comment: That throws an exception: `"Property 'otherAttr' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable."`.